# Add title, time and link to next chat event in the front-page chat widgets

Tags: feature-request, chat

On Wednesday, March 23, 2011, the [Sci-Fi And Fantasy site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) is going to have a [recommendation chat event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule).  The only problem is that I think that only regulars will know about this event, because they are the ones who enter the chat rooms.

I'm proposing that below the list of chat members in the front-page chat widget, we add a link with the time and title of the next chat event.  That way non-regular users can see that there is an event coming up and they can click on it to see what's going on.

Chat widget now:

[image]

Proposed Chat widget:

[image]

I guess the only draw-back is that the right-bar is longer, and the widget is less concise.  But I think those negatives will probably be offset by increased community involvement.

Comment: Do we need those glasses?

Comment: @random: I'm sorry could you be more specific?

Comment: **"Now in 3D!"** (Popcorn comes extra. Avoid the "butter")

Comment: @random: lol I see what you mean, I just used the existing link text from the [chat event page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule).  So as to not complicate the issue.

Comment: Ironically, because it says "3d" it complicates the issue.  Sometimes I just can't win :).

Comment: And as you get closer to the event things become flatter

Comment: I changed it to "5d", hopefully that will be more pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have [the floater on SFF.meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/periodic-recommendation-chats), you can juice it with that [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag and have that show up on the main side where it should get some more eyeballs.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to do that, but I never got around to asking the other mods about it.  I guess I'll do it and let them roll it back if they don't like it.

Comment: Do people ever read those featured Meta posts? I hardly ever pay attention to these, even on the sites where I do regularly participate on Meta.